# How do I clean a whiteboard that hasn't been cleaned in a while?

Tags: cleaning, home

I have a whiteboard (dry-erase) that hasn't been cleaned in a long time, and that now has stuff dried on it. Even though it was originally written with dry-erase markers, it's been too long, and they've dried onto the whiteboard. Using a regular tissue doesn't cut it.

Short of buying a new whiteboard, is there any way to get it looking clean again?

Comment: I believe the solution to be the same... Dry erase a big chunk over it, let it sit for a minute and wipe that board