# How To Restore a Whiteboard Coated Surface?

Tags: cleaning, home

I have a whiteboard wall and it's now looking dull. Is there a way to restore to its original condition?

Comment: How is the wall / board built? Just white paint on the wall? A painted sheet of metal, attached to the wall? A plastic sheet covering a sheet of metal, attached to the wall? Other?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/303/6973

Comment: Hi Matthew, Welcome to Lifehacks. If you make a mark with a fresh marker and after a few minutes erasing it leaves a "shadow" of the mark, the smooth finish is gone and reapplication of the Whiteboard finish paint is recommended.

Comment: Also possible duplicate https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/17/permanent-marker-on-a-dry-erase-board

Answer (score 1):

Dab a little 90% alcohol (the type you would use to disinfect stuff) on a paper towel, and wipe away. Most whiteboard pen ink is soluble is alcohol so this usually gets rid of mot stains.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be interpreted a few ways:

1. Dirty board
2. The board could be scratched up

So for 1. You’re going to need: 
 One of the following:

- Acetone
- Isopropyl alcohol
- White board cleaner from the manufacturer

And a clean cloth preferably white in color.

Then you’re going to place the compound in a spray bottle and spray the board. Give it 3 or 5 secs and wipe off.

if it isn’t exactly to your liking repeat previous step.

Now if it’s the second part either get a new board or paint over it.

Comment: Won't Acetone remove the WB treatment?

Comment: @Stan depends on the board, white board cleaner is the safest.

Comment: You should add that comment and maybe reorder the points 'safest' before risky to improve your answer.